# Extract function in oracle with space

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a COLUMN in Oracle11g table CLOB as data type with value as below :

### COLUMN DATA

```
<Nodes>
  <Node NodeType="Start"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node1"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node2"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node3"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node4"/>
</Nodes>
```

When i run Query as below

### QUERY

```
select EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(Node_XML), /Nodes/Node/@NodeType) from table_name where pk='key1';
```

### Output:

```
StartNode1Node2Node3Node4
```

But I need ouptut as :

### Expected Output:

```
Start  Node1  Node2  Node3  Node4
```

I Need a space(or any delimiter) to use the query in java code.
Is there any other function in oracle to achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Since `EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` are deprecated from 11g and upwards, it sounds like a job for `XMLTABLE` and `LISTAGG` instead:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, '<Nodes>
  <Node NodeType="Start"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node1"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node2"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node3"/>
  <Node NodeType="Node4"/>
</Nodes>' xdata from dual)
select sd.id,
       listagg(nodetype, ',') within group (order by x.id) nodes
from   sample_data sd
       cross join xmltable('/Nodes/Node'
                           passing xmltype(sd.xdata)
                           columns id for ordinality,
                                   nodetype varchar2(10) path '@NodeType') x
group by sd.id;

        ID NODES                                   
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 Start,Node1,Node2,Node3,Node4
```